# A simple way to replace all column values in a loop of a dataframe according to another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-wrangling

I want to change the correct option's value or simply create a new column with all by the information given in the correct option's value, I tried looping through index and changing it but the comparsion code is just not working, I even tried iteritems before but failed. can someone tell how to solve this.

```
 In[] df
Out[] **ques opt1 opt2 opt3 opt4  correctOpt**
        q1   red  blue grey green opt1
        q2   red  blue grey green opt3
```

I tried this

```
for col in df.index:
 df.replace(to_replace=df['Correct Option'][col], value = df[[col],['Correct option']],[col])
```

got *positonal agrument follows keyword agrument* error

I am trying to get this as a output or same column row values in a new column

```
Out[] correctOpt
      red
      grey
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the apply function as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['q1','red','blue','grey','green','opt1'],
                    ['q2','red','blue','grey','green','opt3']], 
                    columns=['ques','opt1','opt2','opt3','opt4','correctOpt'])

df.apply(lambda row: row['opt'+row['correctOpt'][3]], axis=1)
```

The apply function applies a custom function to each row in a DataFrame. 'axis=1' gives the custom function the DataFrame ROW as an argument (instead of column), then row['correctOpt'][3] gets the correct option number, and row['opt'+row['correctOpt'][3]] gets the result from the opt column.